# Build to static libs and DPDK into an image file

Tags: makefile, libs, dpdk

I have a project lets call it AB, which looks a follows:

```
/path/to/<br>
---|dpdk-stable-17.05.1/...<br>
---|AB/<br>
------|main.cpp<br>
------|Makefile<br>
------|dir1/<br>
----------|c1.c<br>
----------|c2.c<br>
----------|c3.c<br>
----------|h1.h<br>
----------|Makefile<br>
------|dir2/<br>
----------|h2.h<br>
----------|cpp1.cpp<br>
----------|cpp2.cpp<br>
----------|Makefile<br>
```

I've compiled the dpdk with make install successfuly.
I am trying to create dir1.a and dir2.a and to build together with main.cpp and of-course the DPDK libs an "AB" image file.

The Makefile in AB (the main makefile) looks as follows:

```
>DPDK_VER=dpdk-stable-17.05.1
>
>RTE_SDK=$(shell pwd | sed -n 's/AB.*//p')/$(DPDK_VER)<br>
>RTE_TARGET=build
>
>include $(RTE_SDK)/mk/rte.vars.mk
>
>XXFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -I../dir1/ -g<br>
>CXXFLAGS += -std=c++1y -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS<br>
>CFLAGS += -g -O0 -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wno-unused-value<br>
>LDLIBS += -lfuse -lstdc++ --start-group -ldir1 -ldir2
>
>LDFLAGS +=  --end-group
>
>APP = AB
>
>SRCS-y :=  main.cpp
> 
>OBJS-y := main.o
>           
>SRCS-y := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.c,$(SRCS-y))<br>
>OBJS-y := $(patsubst %.o,obj/%.o,$(OBJS-y))
>
>DIRS-y = <br>
>DIRS-y += dir1<br>
>DIRS-y += dir2
>
>.PHONY: dirs-y $(DIRS-y)
>
>include $(RTE_SDK)/mk/rte.subdir.mk<br>
>include $(RTE_SDK)/mk/rte.extapp.mk
>
>.PHONY: clean<br>
>clean:<br>
>   rm -rf *.o build/*.o build/$(APP)
```

The Makefile in dir1 looks:

```
>DPDK_VER=dpdk-stable-17.05.1
>
>RTE_SDK=$(shell pwd | sed -n 's/AB.*//p')/$(DPDK_VER)<BR>
>RTE_TARGET=build

>include $(RTE_SDK)/mk/rte.vars.mk
>
>export RTE_OUTPUT=$(shell pwd)/../build/
>
>CXXFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -g<BR>
>CXXFLAGS += -std=c++1y -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -lgnustl_shared<br>
>CFLAGS += -g -O0 -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wno-unused-value -I../dir2
>
>LIB = dir1.a
>
>SRCS-y :=  c1.c c2.c c3.c<br>
>OBJS-y :=  c1.o c2.o c3.o
>                           
>SRCS-y := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.c,$(SRCS-y))<br>
>OBJS-y := $(patsubst %.o,obj/%.o,$(OBJS-y))
>
>include $(RTE_SDK)/mk/rte.extlib.mk
>
>.PHONY: all<br>
>   all
>
>.PHONY: clean<br>
>clean:<br>
>   rm -rf *.o *.a ../build/lib/$(LIB)'
```

The Makefile in dir2 looks:

```
>DPDK_VER=dpdk-stable-17.05.1
>
>RTE_SDK=$(shell pwd | sed -n 's/AB.*//p')/$(DPDK_VER)<br>
>RTE_TARGET=build
>   
>include $(RTE_SDK)/mk/rte.vars.mk
>
>export RTE_OUTPUT=$(shell pwd)/../build/
>   
>CXXFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -g<br>
>CXXFLAGS += -std=c++1y -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -lgnustl_shared -I../dir1 -I.<br>
>CFLAGS += -g -O0 -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wno-unused-value<br>
>
>LIB = dir1.a
>
>SRCS-y := cpp1.cpp cpp2.cpp<br>
>OBJS-y := cpp1.o cpp2.o
>
>SRCS-y := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.c,$(SRCS-y))<br>
>OBJS-y := $(patsubst %.o,obj/%.o,$(OBJS-y))
>
>include $(RTE_SDK)/mk/rte.extlib.mk
>
>.PHONY: all<br>
>   all
>   
>.PHONY: clean<br>
>clean:<br>
>   rm -rf *.o *.a ../build/lib/$(LIB)
```

the *make* output is:

> == Build /dir1
>    CC c1.o
>    CC c2.o
>    CC c3.o
>    AR dir1.a
>    INSTALL-LIB dir1.a
>   == Build /dir2
>   g++ -m64 -pthread  -march=native -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE2 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE3 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSSE3 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE4_1 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE4_2  -I/path/to/AB/build/include -I/path/to/dpdk-stable-17.05.1/build/include -include /path/to/dpdk-stable-17.05.1/build/include/rte_config.h -g -std=c++1y -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -lgnustl_shared -I../dir1 -I.   -c -o cpp1.o cpp2.cpp
>   g++ -m64 -pthread  -march=native -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE2 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE3 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSSE3 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE4_1 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE4_2  -I/path/to/AB/build/include -I/path/to/dpdk-stable-17.05.1/build/include -include /path/to/dpdk-stable-17.05.1/build/include/rte_config.h -g -std=c++1y -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -lgnustl_shared -I../dir1 -I.   -c -o cpp2.o cpp2.cpp
>   
>    AR dir2.a
>   INSTALL-LIB dir2.a
>   /path/to/dpdk-stable-17.05.1/mk/internal/rte.install-post.mk:98: warning: overriding recipe for target `_postinstall'<br>
>   /path/to/dpdk-stable-17.05.1/mk/internal/rte.install-post.mk:75: warning: ignoring old recipe for target`_postinstall'
>   /path/to//dpdk-stable-17.05.1/mk/internal/rte.clean-post.mk:61: warning: overriding recipe for target `_postclean'<br>
>   /path/to//dpdk-stable-17.05.1/mk/internal/rte.clean-post.mk:38: warning: ignoring old recipe for target`_postclean'
>   /path/to//dpdk-stable-17.05.1/mk/internal/rte.build-post.mk:38: warning: overriding recipe for target `_postbuild'<br>
>   /path/to/dpdk-stable-17.05.1/mk/internal/rte.build-post.mk:38: warning: ignoring old recipe for target`_postbuild'
>   /path/to/AB/Makefile:40: warning: overriding recipe for target `clean'<br>
>   /path/to/dpdk-stable-17.05.1/mk/rte.app.mk:308: warning: ignoring old recipe for target`clean'
>   g++ -m64 -pthread  -march=native -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE2 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE3 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSSE3 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE4_1 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE4_2  -I/path/to/AB/build/include -I/path/to/dpdk-stable-17.05.1/build/include -include /path/to/dpdk-stable-17.05.1/build/include/rte_config.h -I../dir1/ -g  -std=c++1y -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS   -c -o main.o /path/to/AB/main.cpp
>    LD AB
>   == Build /path/to/AB/dir1
>   make[2]: *** No rule to make target `c1.o', needed by`dir1.a'.  >Stop.
>
>   make[1]: *** [dir1] Error 2
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

The dir.a dir2.a and AB image are all created!
BUT:
1) why does the make goes back to Build dir1 at the end and announces that the c1.o is missing for dir1.o?
2) How to get rid of the "warning: ignoring old recipe for target `XXX'"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code is not quite reproducible, but I guess the root cause is that there are two includes in the main Makefile, `rte.subdir.mk` and `rte.extapp.mk`.

Try to put the `main.cpp` into an `src` directory and use just `rte.subdir.mk` in the main Makefile, moving all application build functionality to `src/Makefile`...